# select element based on class and attribute value

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to use Xpath in order to select an HTML tag based on its value

Here is my html code:

```
 <span class="yellowbird">Continue</span>
 <span class="yellowbird">Stop</span>
```

I can select the span elements with a specific class value using

```
//span[contains(@class, 'yellowbird')]
```

However I'm struggling to select only the element which contains the value "Continue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the syntax I used to make this work using request.xpath and scrapy

```
//span[contains(@class, 'yellowbird')][1]//text()='Continue'
```

Answer (score 2):

This XPath expression will select any `span` element whose `class` attribute equals `yellowbird` and text equals `Continue`:

```
//span[@class='yellowbird' and text()='Continue']
```